# Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query:

```
$users = Store::find(auth()->user()->store_id)
            ->users()
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->select('id', 'name')
            ->get();
```

The error I got:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id'
in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `id`, `name`, 
`store_user`.`store_id` as `pivot_store_id`,
`store_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `store_user`.
`vip_price` as `pivot_vip_price`, `store_user`.`public_price` as `pivot_public_price`, 
`store_user`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `store_user`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` 
from `users` inner join `store_user` on `users`.`id` = `store_user`.`user_id` where `store_user`.`store_id` = 14 and `name` LIKE %test%)"
```

I want to select the columns in users relation

`users` in Store Model is:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Note: I know I can put select in relation directly but I need another way! because it will affect another place

Comment: The error you are seeing is inconsistent with a query on a single table, where duplicate alias/column names should not be a problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated the question with full error

Comment: Both tables have an `id` column.  You need to either alias them as separate things, or select `id` prefaced by a table alias.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Can't you just write `->select('users.id', 'name')`? Sorry for my ignorance, don't know the ORM you're using

Comment: @LarsStegelitz that's worked!

Answer (score 0):

Both table have `id` column and that is the issue when run above query.

If you need id and name from users table then use `closure` function with the `with()` method.

```
$users = Store::find(auth()->user()->store_id)
        ->with(['users' => function( $query ) use( $request ) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            $query->select('id', 'name');
        }])
        ->get();
```

Comment: that get all stores! I need to get users not stores